# What is the difference between stomata in evergreen broadleaf trees and deciduous broadleaf trees?

Tags: trees

They must have some difference in their stomatal density /whether they are hypostomatous or amphistomatous/whatever, mustn't they?

Comment: @Christiaan - Evergreen have needles. Broadleaf have broader leaves, which are generally larger than needles. It is not unreasonable that two trees of similar size need a similar number of stomata. So the question is how do the stomata of the two types of leaf differ? Do needles have a higher density? My first thought would be that evergreen trees must have more needles than broadleaf trees have leaves.